# How to Access an attribute from the same stage in mongo pipleline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
stage2 = {
  "$project": {
    "time_interval_mins": {"$divide": [{"$subtract": ["$to", "$from"]}, 60000]},
    "consumption_hourly": {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 60]},
    "calculation2": {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 3600]},
  },
}
```

I want to use time_interval_mins for various other calculation like the one used in consumption_hourly in the same stage. wanted to know if something like this is possible. I have seen how `$let` works, but as per my understanding we can only return a single value.

I can always create a new stage after this and use `time_interval_mins` whereever required, but I feel there must be a better way to do this that I am missing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned you need to use `$addFields` or `$let` if you want to do it in one pipeline stage. [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) can return an object like below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { "time_interval_mins": {"$divide": [{"$subtract": ["$to", "$from"]}, 60000]} },
                    in: {
                        time_interval_mins: "$$time_interval_mins",
                        consumption_hourly: {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 60]},
                        calculation2: {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 3600]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwDVikmAQHk)

You can also try [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) if you need to propmote your object to top level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { "time_interval_mins": {"$divide": [{"$subtract": ["$to", "$from"]}, 60000]} },
                    in: {
                        time_interval_mins: "$$time_interval_mins",
                        consumption_hourly: {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 60]},
                        calculation2: {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$properties.consumption", "$$time_interval_mins"]}, 3600]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FeAK2dzMJP7)